# Social sharing plugin phonegap Share value

Tags: javascript, html, forms, cordova, social-networking

I want to share text from textarea input value.

This my code :

```
<textarea type="text" id="source"   tabindex="1" name="source" placeholder="Text to be translated" ></textarea>             

<textarea id="results_body" onfocus="ok=1" cols="100" rows="6" style="height:10%;" ></textarea>

<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('textarea value')>share only</button>
```

Comment: What is the question? How to get the text area value? If so, which text area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you only want to get the text area values to where you currently have `'textarea value'`, you can replace it with

```
document.getElementById('source').value
```

to be like

```
share(document.getElementById('source').value)
```

Comment: Thank's Mr sanfor , the problem resolved thank's thank's much